# Generated RIA Entity 'Unit' conflicts with Rx 'Unit'

Tags: .net, silverlight, ria, system.reactive

I have a Silverlight application that uses RIA Services.  One of the entities is named `Unit`.  I recently tried to use Reactive Extensions, but when I added a reference to `System.CoreEx` I encountered a conflict between `System.Unit` and my business object `CE.EMS.GenUnits.Model.Unit`.

I can alias the business object in non-generated code like this:

```
using Unit = CE.EMS.GenUnits.Model.Unit;
```

But the generated service code still has the conflict.  How can I solve the conflict without changing the name of my business object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of Rx, where I'm fairly sure it's hidden under System.Reactive.Unit

Comment: The latest version is 'experimental'.

Comment: While it's the 'experimental branch', they just made the split, no experimental features have yet been added - it's also an extremely well-tested codebase.

Comment: They made two branches, experimental and stable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and had to change the name of my business object :(